# Regarding regular expression

Tags: angularjs

Need a regular expression for Input field that it should not accept ex potentials(eg: 1e0) and which allows 2 deciamls(eg:2.24).

I used the following regexp "value": "/^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0,4})?$/",...but it is allowing 1e0

Comment: Was my answer helpful, didnt it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the dot. You need to escape it.

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,4})?$/
```

Here a working example https://regex101.com/r/sQ8qU2/1

***btw.:***
*If only 2 decimals are allowed, than `{0,4}` would have to be changed to `{0,2}`.*